# tkinter, recuperar contenido todos los entry

Tags: python, tkinter

Tengo una interfaz visual construida en Tkinter que me genera una x cantidad de

```
    title = Label(lienzo,
               text=titulocaja,
               font=("verdana",10),
               fg="white",
               bg="black")
    title.place(x=xtitulo, y=ytitulo)
    nombrecaja = ttk.Entry()
    nombrecaja.place(x=xcaja, y=ycaja)
```

En total debo tener quizás una 15 cajas de texto insertadas en el código a través de esta función, pero podrían llegar a ser muchas más dependiendo de cuántos datos quiera insertar el usuario.
El tema es que ahora necesito recuperar el contenido de esas entry a través de un botón "Save" y no estoy seguro de cómo hacerlo.

Hay alguna forma de implementar un loop for que por cada entry tome el contenido y lo rescate?
Muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Claro que hay forma, simplemente guarda los entrys en una [lista](https://entrenamiento-python-basico.readthedocs.io/es/latest/leccion3/tipo_listas.html) y recorre esa lista, obteniendo asi cada entry.

Comment: Pero la función solo se encarga de crear los entry. El usuario ingresa el contenido de forma posterior :v si implemento el loop para recuperar la información en el mismo momento de crear el entry solo voy a estar guardando el campo en blanco

Comment: Tenías razón xD no sé como demonios no se me ocurrió antes. Muchísimas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: De nada! No pasa nada xD